# SUPEE8788 and Wishlist (view.phtml) file

Tags: security, patches, supee-8788

When I was installing supee 8788, it threw a HUNK error on the following line

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view1.phtml
```

basically it was looking to modify view.phtml but in my case I for some reason had `view1.phtml` as a file.

I renamed the file as view.phtml and SUPEE 8788 installed perfectly

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view.phtml
```

Now, I am browsing frontend of magento ( especially wishlist section) and everything is working fine even when the file is called `view.phtml`. I want to make sure I am not missing anything, usually when you rename a file there expected some sort of error, but in my case everything is working properly.

**Anyone could suggest what does this file do ? Maybe I am looking for errors in wrong areas of frontend website.**

Answer (score 0):

This file is not a file provided by Magento out of the box.

Possibilities:

- Someone who was working on the theme created this file as a backup of the original `view.phtml`
- Someone who was working on the theme used this file directly in the theme.

In the first case, you won't have any issue. However, in the second case you'll have to ensure this file is not declared as a template anywhere. To find out, run the following command on your magento store:

```
grep -ri "wishlist/view1.phtml" .
```

If you don't get any result, that means you're all good ;)

If you get a result, feel free to post it as comment and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks you for responding. If the file view.phtml is not part of Magento. Any ideas why super 8788 patches it? I am think the best way is to rename it to views.phtml and installed 8788 update. After update is complete simply change it back to view1.html like it was originally. What do you think?

Comment: @Icon you misread my answer: `view1.phtml` is not part of Magento. `view.phtml` is part of Magento

Comment: Oh, strange, I never had view.phtml in Magento searched full site... the only I could find is view1.phtml. I guess I will rename, patch and rename back to view1. Store running for years with view1 file , no problem.

Comment: @Icon yeah you can try that but it'd be better to find out why your store is using `view1.phtml` instead of `view.phtml`

Comment: I checked and for wishlist/view1.phtml there there are no results. I guess someone made mistake and forgot to remove "1" from filename. I am wondering, how come the wishlist functions perfectly even with view1.phtml ??